# no points in chart series but chart is drawing correctly

Tags: c#, charts, drawing

I'm trying to add a `tooltip` to chart series but the every series has zero `points`. How is that possible because the chart is drawing as it should be?

Here is the code for the `tooltip`:

```
ChartDurchflussKW.DataSource = dsDurchflussProKW.Tables[0];
ChartDurchflussKW.DataBind();

        for (int i = 1; i < dsDurchflussProKW.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ChartDurchflussKW.Series.Add(dsDurchflussProKW.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString());
            ChartDurchflussKW.Series[ChartDurchflussKW.Series.Count - 1].XValueMember = "KW";
            ChartDurchflussKW.Series[ChartDurchflussKW.Series.Count - 1].YValueMembers = dsDurchflussProKW.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();

            foreach (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dp in ChartDurchflussKW.Series[ChartDurchflussKW.Series.Count - 1].Points)
            {
                dp.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                dp.LabelFormat = "N";
                dp.LabelBackColor = Color.White;
                dp.LabelAngle = -90;
                dp.ToolTip = "KW " + dp.AxisLabel.ToString() + ": " + dp.YValues[0].ToString("N0");
            }
        }
```

The chart is drawed with the values as expected but without the tooltips:
[image]

So the chart must have at least one point for every series or where did he get his values for drawing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error: After adding the `series` I have to `databind()` the chart. At this moment the `series` have their `points`. After that in the next loop I can edit the `points`.